# difference between Nokia's MeeGo 1.2 "Harmattan" and intel Meego?

Tags: compatibility, nokia, maemo, meego, meego-harmattan

Nokia has recently announced Nokia N9 with MeeGo 1.2 "Harmattan. Some forums are saying 
that it is differed from intel MeeGo. Is it true? What is Maemo?

Is Maemo same as MeeGo Harmattan? Where can we download SDK to develop applications for it with simulator? Is Intel meego sdk (Intel note book, tablets) enough? Any guide please?

Answer (score 7):

> Nokia has recently announced Nokia N9 with MeeGo 1.2 "Harmattan. Some forums are saying that it is differed from intel MeeGo. Is it true?

They have different package managers. Nokia's MeeGo is **DEB**-based, Intel's MeeGo is **RPM**-based.

Nokia's MeeGo 1.2 `Harmattan API` **=** Intel's MeeGo 1.2 `Core API` **+** Nokia `Specific APIs`

So, the main part of the API including **Qt 4.7.2** and **Qt Mobility 1.2** is well compatible.

See also [binary compatibility report between MeeGo 1.2 Core and MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan on x86](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/compatibility/MeeGo_1.2_Core_to_MeeGo_1.2_Harmattan/x86/abi_compat_report.html) generated by the [abi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/abi-compliance-checker/) tool.

[image]

From the Nokia [Glossary](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Harmattan:Developer_Library/Reference_documentation/Glossary):

> **MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan API**
>
> The official name for Harmattan API. A recommended set of APIs in the Harmattan platform to be used for
>   application development. MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan API consists of **MeeGo API** and **Nokia Specific APIs**, and it is a subset of Platform API.
>
> **MeeGo API**
>
> The set of APIs that are supported by all MeeGo-compliant devices and available for MeeGo application
>   development. MeeGo API is a future-proof set of APIs that is forward-compatible within a major MeeGo
>   release. MeeGo API is a part of MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan API.
>
> **Nokia Specific APIs**
>
> Nokia Specific APIs contain additional libraries that can be used when creating applications for Nokia
>   devices. Nokia provides compatibility to this API set for the next two major Nokia releases. Nokia Specific
>   APIs are a part of MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan API.

Other questions:

> What is maemo?

**Maemo** is the Linux-based innovative platform from Nokia started in 2005. It's installed on N900 (Maemo 5), N800 (Maemo 4) and other experimental devices.

> Is maemo same as MeeGo Harmattan?

Yes, **Maemo 6** and **MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan** are two names of the same platform.

> Where can we download SDK to develop applications for it with simulator?

The Harmattan Platform SDK including the emulator is [here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/platform-sdk/).

> Any guide please?

- [Harmattan Platform Guide](https://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Harmattan:Platform_Guide)
- [Develop for the Nokia N9](http://developer.nokia.com/Devices/MeeGo)
- [Harmattan API Documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/unstable/beta/api_refs/)